# Open problems related with Berezinskii-Kosterlitz-Thouless phase transition

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, phase-transition

I was studying about BKT transitions and after some articles and books, I ended up with a question about the theory developed by the three scientists:

> What open problems (if their exists) in current physics are related to these phase transitions?

For example, could there be a general theorem that governed a general description of this theory, as for example the Mermin-Wagner-Hohenberg-Coleman theorem does in the occurrence of phase transitions for systems of $d\leqslant 2$ with continuous symmetry that is not spontaneously broken?

I don't know if this type of question is compatible with the stack, but it was the only place that came to mind to ask.

Comment: Since you mention *theorems*, let me just say this: while the existence of a BKT phase transition in the 2d classical XY model (and a few other related models) has been known rigorously since a celebrated [work by Fröhlich and Spencer](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01208273) in 1981, it is still a completely open problem to *prove* that there is no massless phase in the 2d classical Heisenberg model. From the point of view of mathematical physics (as in "establishing mathematically rigorous results"), this is certainly the most glaring hole in this topic.

Comment: Is it expected that massless phases occur in the 2D classical Heisenberg model? Why?

Comment: Yes, it is conjectured that the 2-point function decays exponentially *at all temperatures* for all $O(N)$-models with $N>2$. Supposedly, it is the fact that the group $SO(2)$ is abelian, while the groups $SO(N)$, $N \geq 3$, are not, that is responsible for the difference in behavior. I do not understand that, but I am sure some other people here do. See, for instance, [this old review by Kogut](https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.51.659). This prediction is due to Polyakov, see [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370269375901616).